# How to print dates of weekdays only (not weekends) for a range of days by date, for a range of months?

Tags: python, date, range

I need to figure out in python how to (in pesudo)

```
x = month-begin
y = month-end

for range in (x through y) 
  print(dates of weekdays - Monday trough Friday)
```

Comment: check out the [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use date.weekday(). Following your pseudo-code example:

```
for day in range (x through y)
    if day.weekday() in range(0,5):
        print(day)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the datetime module:

```
import datetime
current=datetime.datetime(2018,8,14,14,00)  
end=datetime.datetime(2018,12,1,14,00) 
while current<end:
    current+=datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    if current.weekday()<5:
        print(current.strftime("%-m/%-d"))
```